# Clicking the listview and be able to get a timePicker

Tags: android, android-listview

So this list its working in this way,when i click on the item,the item get deleted.So what i want its that when i click on the item,its have to show me the TimeDialog(**TimePicker**) to  change date and time.

```
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(id.list);
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)       {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String rowId = mCursor.getString(0); //Column 0 of the cursor is the id
            mDb.delete(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{rowId});
            mCursor.requery();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

****Here is my MainActivity,I think this will be helpful!!Include also the Listview!****

```
class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TaskTbl";
public static final String COL_TXT = "Text";
public static final String COL_DATE = "Date";
public static final String COL_TIME = "Time";
private static final String STRING_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
    +COL_TXT+" VARCHAR(250), "+COL_DATE+" VARCHAR(20), "+COL_TIME+" VARCHAR(20));";


public MyDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(STRING_CREATE);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(2);
    cv.put(COL_TXT, "New Entry");
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}


   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

public static final int RESULT_CODE = 1; 


MyDbHelper mHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDb;
Cursor mCursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
Intent weather;     
Intent i;
String text;
String date;
String time;
ListView mList;
Intent nTaskScreen ;


public TextView timeText;
public TextView dateText;
public EditText taskText;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
    dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);
    taskText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    mHelper = new MyDbHelper(getApplicationContext());

    Button showBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shTask);
    showBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {




        }
    });


    Button nTaskBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nTask);
    nTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            nTaskScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, new_task.class);
            startActivityForResult(nTaskScreen, RESULT_CODE);

        }
    });

    Button wthrBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wthrBtn);
    registerForContextMenu(wthrBtn);


    mList = (ListView) findViewById(id.list);
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


            int hourOfDay = 0, minute = 0;




            TimePickerDialog tp = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    mTimeSetListener, hourOfDay, minute, false);
            tp.show();
        };


    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            timeText.setText("" + hourOfDay + "" + minute);
        };

    };

    });
    }


public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", MyDbHelper.COL_TXT, MyDbHelper.COL_TIME};
    mCursor = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String[] headers = new String[] {MyDbHelper.COL_TXT, MyDbHelper.COL_TIME};
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            mCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CODE)
    {

        String text = data.getStringExtra("text");
        String date = data.getStringExtra("date");
        String time = data.getStringExtra("time");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Registration was successfull! \nTask: " +text + "\nOn: " + date + "\nat:" + time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(2);
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_TXT, text.toString());
        //cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_DATE, date); //Insert 'now' as the date
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_TIME, time);

        mDb.insert(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        mCursor.requery();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        text = null;

            //mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO TaskTbl (text,time,date) VALUES(" + "'" + text + "', '" + time + "', '" + date + "');");      

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}



 }
```

Comment: You want to delete the item OR you want to show the TimeDialog on list item click?Can you explain your requirement more briefly?

Comment: When I click the item I want to show me the TimeDialog.And if its possible to save it in the database. So do u want me to show u my project??The 2 Activitys i have,it will be more easier?

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically adding views in layout, you can save clicked position & then can set text there

Add views to layout

```
final View v = View.inflate(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_timw,null);
final TextView txTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
EditText hour11 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.hour11);
EditText hour22 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.hour22);
EditText minute11 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.minute11);
EditText minute22 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.minute22);
ArrayListhour11.add(hour11);
ArrayListhour22.add(hour22);
ArrayListminute11.add(minute11);
ArrayListminute22.add(minute22);
```

then save clciked Position & then get value in Time Or Date set.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener1 =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view1, int selectedHour,
                                    int selectedMinute) {
                ArrayListhour11.get(clickedPos).setText(selectedHour+"");
                ArrayListminute11.get(clickedPos).setText(selectedMinute+"");
                showDialog(BOutTIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass intent  with date and time data and then on save button click you can save that data into Database and After saving data onResume of previous activity you can reload cursor and reload data into listview.And please state that what you exactly want.
You can do it like this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View arg1, int arg2,
                long id) {
            int hourOfDay = 0, minute = 0;


            TimePickerDialog tp = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    mTimeListener, hourOfDay, minute, false);
            tp.show();

        }
    });
```

Where mTimeListener is as below:

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener maxtime = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textview.setText("" + hourOfDay + "" + minute);
    }
};
```

Hope it works for you...

Comment: I want it simple,can u show me the code.So when i click on the item in the list I want me to show the TimeDialg(or TimePicker)to change date and time.

Comment: Now you can refer answer..@Arjeta Ballazhi

Comment: I've tried and it shows the TimePicker,but when i choose the time and click Set,then i'll get a error and the App get Closed. Any idea? because i want it also to be stored in the list the Time i Chose.

Comment: Yes,when I click on the set button...But I ll show u my whole project,then its easier